# Hi! I was wondering: Nostalgia ? Wanderlust?

Tags: meaning, etymology

How did these foreign terms for emotions get into English?
They all describe a feeling of something imagined. Some examples:

Nostalgia
Wanderlust
Fernweh

This group of words amazes me and makes me fascinated with the meaning behind them. English is not my first language.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Could you [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/249179/edit) your post to be more specific as to what you mean by "what kind"? There are innumerable ways to classify words.

Comment: Foreign words..

Comment: @zeroflagL: More specifically, foreign [***abstract nouns***](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-abstract-nouns.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers New Latin and German ones to be even more specific ;)

Comment: This is actually a good question from the point of view of historical linguistics. These words are compound words that come from German. Nostalgia is a 1668 rendering of 'heimweh', the opposite of 'fernweh'. I could write much more on this, because modern compound words that come from German can be compared to kennings in OE.

Answer (score 2):

Nostalgia is a longing for the past.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgia

Fernweh and Wanderlust are, strictly speaking, German words but I sometimes hear them used in English conversation and literature.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fernweh

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wanderlust

All these describe a feeling of longing for something. A similar (non-English) word would be Saudade

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saudade

If you could please be a little more specific with your question I could give a better answer.